# Icon above scroll bar area in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, monterey

I recently noticed this strange icon on my terminal. Its placed at top right corner where scroll bar starts. Hovering it, it says `split pane` in tool tip description. When it is clicked, it actually opens up new instance horizontally within the same terminal similar to `tmux`.

Also when I right click it, it gives super awesome profiles to choose from like `basic`, `grass`, `homebrew`, etc.

**version info**

- macos : Version 12.5.1 (21G83)
- terminal : Version 2.12.7 (445)
- zsh : zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)

**snapshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am just curious to know how did this feature got enabled? Yeah I did installed `npm` for `nodejs`. But I doubt this has anything to do with npm

Answer (score 2):

I think you just never spotted it before.

It's there all the way back to El Capitan, OS X 10.11, though the right click is slightly different back then.

Screenshot from an El Cap VM
[image]

Comment: No it wasn't there before. I used it last month extensively. I also asked few other friends of mine. They have same version but do not have this feature. BUT I AM SO RELIEVED to know at least someone has it also. Thanks for sharing this information.

Comment: I didn't know it was switchable. It must be there by default, as Terminal is one of those things I never touch the prefs on. I don't know it or use it enough. It's there on every Mac we have here, from 2009 to 2021 models & their different OSes.

Comment: I am still in search of source which can tell its configurable.. when we see MacBook terminal Google images, most of them are without this icon.